# How to use Paper-Dialog in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015173/how-to-use-paper-dialog-polymer-element) relates to Polymer 0.5 and seems not to work in Polymer 1.0. For a beginner like me, I see no clear implementation; just the actual function code and not a "How to". Here is my simple setup that does not work (assume I have imported all elements):

```
<dom-element id="my-app">
 <template>
    <paper-button raised id="toggleDialog"></paper-button>
    <paper-dialog entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
      exit-animation="fade-out-animation" onclick="{{toggleDialog}}">
      <h2>Header</h2>
      <div>Dialog body</div>
    </paper-dialog> 
 </template>
 <script>
  Polymer({
   is: "my-app",
   properties: {
    type: String,
    observer: "" // not important for this example so it's empty.
   },
    // should I put the function here?
    toggleDialog: function() {
      this.$.dialog.toggle();
    }
  });
 </script>
</dom-element>
```

I hope I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: Give us more details: what is happening that you're not expecting to happen? Any error phenomena?

Comment: @doldt I have added the button. Sorry. Nothing happens when button is pressed/clicked/tapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
this.$.dialog.toggle();
```

with:

```
this.$.toggleDialog.toggle();
```

because:

The string after the cash sign `$` needs to match the `id`.

And, finally:

Move the `id="toggleDialog"` attribute from the `<paper-button>` tag to the `<paper-dialog>` tag. Because you want to target the `<paper-dialog>` element with the `.toggle()` method. Not the `<paper-button>` itself.

Comment: Now would you believe that hahaha. Time for a cup of coffee! My eye are not working with me tonight. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: You probably already figured it out, but you will also need to move the `id="toggleDialog"` attribute from the `<paper-button>` tag to the `<paper-dialog>` tag. See the updated, edited answer.